# Unable to obtain key with max or min value from a dict in python(runestone) using max function

Tags: python

```py
sally = "sally sells sea shells by the sea shore"
characters = {}
for i in sally:
    if i not in characters:
        characters[i] = 0
    characters[i] += 1
    best_char = max(characters.keys())
```

The max function displays 'y' as the most frequent letter instead of 's'. This is the runestone off coursera.I've looked up several methods from stack and geeks for geeks but they are either unnecessarily lengthy or complex for me as Im am beginner.
Thanks. I apologize for any mistakes/inconveniences.

Comment: You will get the list of keys , i.e. `['s', 'a', 'y'.....]`. Max function will return 'y' as the biggest value

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues with your code:

- the indention for the max calculation which should be outside of the loop
- your code currently return the `maximum letter` that would be 'y' according to alphanumeric classification whereas you want to see the most occurring letter so you should rank by values instead.

I put below the code that keep the spirit of your approach but you should know that in python you have much more efficient/elegant solution to do what you are trying to achieve

```
    import operator
    
    sally = "sally sells sea shells by the sea shore"
    characters = {}
    for i in sally:
        if i not in characters:
            characters[i] = 0
        characters[i] += 1
    
    best_char = max(characters.values())
    
    best_char = max(characters.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you took maximum of dict keys instead of their counts.
Perhaps you wanted something like this which will return "s":

```
sally = "sally sells sea shells by the sea shore"
characters = {}
for i in sally:
    if i not in characters:
        characters[i] = 0
    characters[i] += 1

counts = sorted([ (k,v) for k,v in characters.items() ], key=lambda x: x[1])
best_char = counts[-1][0] # s
```

Answer (score 0):

This output is expected because you take the maximum value of the keys. The keys are characters represented by ASCII values and because 'y' is the latest letter in the alphabet from your input, it has the max value. In ASCII a = 97, z = 122.

One way to get the key which has the maximum value as its value is:

```
key_with_max_value = max(characters, key=characters.get)
print(key_with_max_value)
```

Python dictionary method `get()` returns a value for the given key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `key=` of the max function

```
sally = "sally sells sea shells by the sea shore"
characters = {}
for i in sally:
    if i not in characters:
        characters[i] = 0
    characters[i] += 1
    best_char = max(characters, key=lambda x: characters[x])
print(best_char)
```

Output

```
s
```

When you are using `max` with a dictionary it will do the max on the keys of the dictionary so with the `key=` value of the max method you can apply lambda that will check in the max value from the values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

```py
from collections import Counter

sally = "sally sells sea shells by the sea shore"

Counter(sally).most_common()[0]

> ('s', 8)
```